# visibility of a div not changing after clicking again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi so a i am trying to buttons and each button deals with the visibility of two side bars. Clicking on **Color** button will open Color Bar and clicking the **theme** button will open the Theme Bar. I am doing this by creating two Jquery click functions and adding Classes.

HTML Part of two buttons

```
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="colorClicked" id="color">Color</td>
            <td class="themeOff" id="theme">Theme</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is my CSS for Buttons and Bars

```
    .colorClicked {
    width:50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #818181;
    border-right: 1px solid #818181;
    border-left: 1px solid #818181;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #818181;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Wire One', Gadget, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

.colorOff {
    width:50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #818181;
    border-top: 0px solid #818181;
    border-right: 0px solid #818181; 
    border-left: 0px solid #818181;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Wire One', Gadget, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

.themeClicked {
    width:50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #818181;
    border-right: 1px solid #818181;
    border-left: 1px solid #818181;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #818181;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Wire One', Gadget, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    }   

.themeOff {
    width:50%;
    border-top: 0px solid #818181;
    border-right: 0px solid #818181;
    border-left: 0px solid #818181;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #818181;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Wire One', Gadget, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

CSS for Bars

```
.colorTabOn {
    visibility:visible;
    }

.colorTabHidden {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    }

.themeTabOn {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:visible;
    }   

.themeTabHidden {
    top: -31.5em;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
```

Jquery

```
    $('#theme').click(function(){
        $('#colorTab').addClass('colorTabHidden', 500);
        $('#themeTab').addClass('themeTabOn', 500);
        $('#theme').addClass('themeClicked', 500);
        $('#color').addClass('colorOff', 500);
});

$('#color').click(function(){
        $('#colorTab').addClass('colorTabOn', 500);
        $('#themeTab').addClass('themeTabHidden', 500);
        $(this).addClass('colorClicked', 500);
        $('#theme').addClass('themeOff', 500);  
});
```

However once i click the #theme button nothing happens to the visibility of the bar. New class is only applied to button and after clicking the #Color button again NOTHING HAPPENS AT ALL.

Help me maybe i am a beginner in Jquery. Thank You

Comment: Not sure, but maybe is not necessary to set any other properties then className in addClass?

Comment: Uh, and in your case it's good to remove unnecessary classes also!

Comment: Agreed with @SemyonVyskubov, when you click the other button, call .removeClass() rather than adding another class that tries to revert the changes

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Well, try this:

```
$('#theme').click(function(){
    $('#colorTab').addClass('colorTabHidden').removeClass('colorTabOn');
    $('#themeTab').addClass('themeTabOn').removeClass('themeTabHidden');
    $('#theme').addClass('themeClicked');
    $('#color').addClass('colorOff');
});

$('#color').click(function(){
    $('#colorTab').addClass('colorTabOn').removeClass('colorTabHidden');
    $('#themeTab').addClass('themeTabHidden').removeClass('themeTabOn');
});
```